# Files 404 unless owned by 0:0

Tags: centos, http-status-code-404, chown

When I upload files to my staging server (CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.26) - such as images or PDFs - via FTP, or by using a file upload script I created (using Laravel 4), they 404 even though they exist.

However, any files that are pulled via git are fine.

I took a look at the difference between ownership of a normally loading file and a 404ing file. When uploaded via FTP or the site, the owner:group is `mobius:mobius`. When pulled by git, it's `0:0`.

When I run `chown -R 0:0 assets/`, any files that previously returned 404 loaded perfectly. However, since the site has an upload feature it would be impractical to have to keep executing this command.

How can I make the server show the file no matter who the owner? `chmod` won't work on its own.

I don't think it's a problem with my `.htaccess` because I deleted it and still got a 404.

**Edit**: It's worth noting that I can access the file using the absolute URL (i.e., not a subdomain)

Comment: Verify that it's not SELinux.

Comment: When I run `sestatus` I get `SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: apache shows a message in the error log when there's a 404. What is the message?

Comment: The line that is added when I try and access an image that 404s is: `[Thu Aug 07 11:32:59 2014] [error] [client 91.214.231.74] Caught race condition abuser. attacker: 0, victim: 501 open file owner: 501, open file: /home/mobius/public_html/clients/munchbox/public/assets/global/pics/posts/5rXHXVT8Yyu94CG.jpg, referer: http://munchbox.mobiusdev.co.uk/`

Comment: It's worth noting that I can access the file using the absolute URL (i.e., not a subdomain)

Comment: Don't run your web server as root.